# Idiomatic way to consume from an endpoint in Apache Camel for the response to an endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

What I want to be able to do is following:

> from(...)
>      .replyWith()
>      .from(...)
>      .end()

So that the response to my producer is taken from the consumption of another endpoint, an example would be something like a REST endpoint for a queue.

Is there an idiomatic way in Camel to be able to do something like the above without grabbing an Endpoint from a CamelContext instance and manually retrieving the contents and setting them into the Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a bit more?

You dont want to just do

from A
  to B

from B
  to C

So that a message send to A will be send to B. And B is processed in another route, and the response from this will be send back to the first route, which will be used as reply to any client invoking A in the first place.

Also if you want something with dynamic endpoints, then you can use the Recipient List EIP pattern
http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Comment: In the example above the request body is irrelevant as the thing of interest is the reply.

Where I mentioned the REST interface to a queue example it would be a web endpoint that when hit with a browser would consume the result from the queue endpoint and then return that to the browser.

Comment: Ah you may want to look at the Content Enricher EIP pattern. Camel has pollEnrich you can use to consume from a queue and "merge" the data

Answer (score 0):

```
from("http://0.0.0.0:9001/getResultsFromQueue")
 .pollEnrich("activemq:queue:myQueue")
 .to("log:test?level=DEBUG");
```